# How do I create Insert Update trigger on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Hi I have 2 tables name say `EmpOne` and `NotificationEmp1` both table having same structure with same column name, I want to insert update record in `NotificationEmp1` table using trigger when I insert update records into `EmpOne`

Comment: Need some information, like what are the keys to the table, what are the columns, are there any special columns like IDENTITY or computed columns, what version of SQL Server are you using...

Comment: There's nothing out of the ordinary about your scenario, and you haven't provided any information, so you might as well have just googled it.  tkerwood's answer is just the skeleton you'd get from Books OnLine (BOL).

Answer (score 1):

Well I fail to see the point of a trigger that keeps a copy of the table exactly in sync, and you've provided very vague specs, but I'll give it a shot.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_EmpOne
ON dbo.EmpOne
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.NotificationEmp1(columns)
        SELECT columns 
        FROM inserted AS i
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 FROM deleted WHERE key_column = i.key_column);

    UPDATE n
        SET col1 = i.col1,
            col2 = i.col2 --, etc etc
    FROM dbo.NotificationEmp1 AS n
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON i.key_column = n.key_column
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d
    ON i.key_column = d.key_column;
END
GO
```

Now don't forget you're going to need something to delete rows from NoticiationEmp1 when rows are deleted from EmpOne. Also there is no error handling here at all - as an example (and this won't raise an error), consider the case where a row has been deleted directly from NotificationEmp1, and is later updated in EmpOne, it will fall through the cracks here...

Answer (score 0):

Within a trigger you have logical (conceptual) tables called "Inserted" and "deleted" that hold the records that have been modified. So you can just insert the records from these.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Employee_Write_Audit] 
   ON  [dbo].[EmpOne]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- all new inserted records and updated.
    Insert into NotificationEmp1 select * from Inserted
    -- just the deleted ones not the updated rows that are being removed.
    Insert into NotificationEmp1 select * from Deleted where EmpOneId not in  (select EmpOneId from inserted)
END
```